# Information about DLL files in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

I am learning Win32 API. 
 I recently stumbled upon the topic of dll. 
I have understood it well, but now I want to find more about dll files.

for example, one of my project uses 38 different dll files, I have made a list of all these dll files.

I know many of these files are from the softwares that i have installed,
but there are many windows specific files as well.
Where can i find information about these dll files given by windows.
All I want to know is what these files do?

I'd appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction, perhaps a good windows book.

Comment: What kind of information do you want that isn't available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) or via [Google](http://www.google.com)?

Comment: ok, for example, one of the DLL files linked to my project was  'ddraw.dll', now i know it is used by DirectX for drawing, but my application is OpenGL based, I wanted to know why this file is needed for an OpenGL application.

i know my question is a bit trivial, but i couldn't find answer to this on either google or MSDN.

Comment: Depends.exe --- see what functions from ddraw.exe are used by your app.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to have clues on why dll is linked is to use Depends.exe. It's in the tool section of visual studio
The most up to date version is there http://www.dependencywalker.com/
It will tell you for each dll what function in each dll is linked and if the dll is linked to your product or included indirectly.
It wont help on that specific problem, but there are more useful tools which unfortunately are not packaged with visual studio highly specialised but useful when needed http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062